# Output in the magento install console

Tags: magento

I am developing an extension on magento and I want to output a message in the black magento connect console after my module installation.

How can I do that?

Comment: I would be interested if this were possible.  I had thought no custom code runs until you leave the connect manager for another page.

Comment: I thought this too, but it's not stupid to think you can display a message after your module installation.